# String conversions are not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to find the subtotal of these items. When I run it, it says that qty variables and price variables strings aren't being converted. When I convert them I still get an error saying that there is something wrong with the format. I am entering in the qtys in a textbox, they are not prefilled. Please help

```
  Private Sub Btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn1.Click
    Dim blackprice As Single = 43.0
    Dim classyheelprice As Single = 48.95
    Dim redprice As Single = 35.95
    Dim weddingprice As Single = 155.65
    Dim sportsprice As Single = 50
    Dim qty1 As Integer = TxtBox1.Text
    Dim qty2 As Integer = TxtBox3.Text
    Dim qty3 As Integer = TxtBox4.Text
    Dim qty4 As Integer = TxtBox5.Text
    Dim qty5 As Integer = TxtBox6.Text
    Dim price1 As Single = Convert.ToSingle(TxtBox2.Text)
    Dim price2 As Single = Convert.ToSingle(TxtBox7.Text)
    Dim price3 As Single = Convert.ToSingle(TxtBox10.Text)
    Dim price4 As Single = Convert.ToSingle(TxtBox9.Text)
    Dim price5 As Single = Convert.ToSingle(TxtBox8.Text)


    price1 = qty1 * blackprice
    Price2 = qty2 * classyheelprice
    Price3 = qty3 * redprice
    Price4 = qty4 * weddingprice
    Price5 = qty5 * sportsprice
    Shoestotal = price1 + price2 + price3 + price4 + price5
    TxtBox11.Text = Shoestotal
```

Error 1: Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
Error 2:Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: You need to post the _full, exact_ error message that is being printed to the console.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.            An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: First, that will not even compile with Option Strict.  Textboxes do not contain integers.  When converting user input you need to always use `TryParse` (`Integer.TryParse`, `Single.TryParse`) because users can and will type anything.  Then look at the code - immediately after you get the price, you overwrite it.  No idea whats in those TextBoxes because the prices are hardcoded

Comment: Is it impossible to calculate a total based on set numbers and what's typed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue with this line :

```
Dim qty1 As Integer = TxtBox1.Text
```

You should cast it :

```
Dim qty1 As Integer = Integer.Parse(textBox1.Text)
```

Comment: I tried that however it says that int. does not accept that number of arguments

Comment: Have you checked that no textbox is emty ?

Comment: They are all empty

Comment: Then it's normal it doesn't work ... You are trying to parse an empty string to an integer wich is impossible.

Comment: ok so how would I calculate a subtotal, allowing the user to type in the quantity

Comment: There is no type called `int` in VB.NET. It's `Integer` or `Int32`.

Comment: @Rob : Try `Integer.Parse(TxtBox1.Text)` instead. It will throw an error if what is entered is not numerical, however.

Comment: @Rob : You should try to catch if the user didn't enter a number in any of the textbox and show a message like 'You must enter all fields to calculate the subtotal'